# How to reverse Z axis in Plotly (javascript)

Tags: javascript, plotly

I wanted to show a 3D surface plot in Plotly but with the Z axis reversed (I'm using it in javascript).
I tried adding those things in layout:

```
scene: { zaxis: { autorange: 'reversed'}}
```

or

```
scene: { zaxis: { autorange: false, range:[15,5]} //reversed min and max
```

but nothing worked.
I know I could do it programatically, reversing my data, but it should be better and simpler if I can just change plotly layout to do it.

Any idea of how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found a recent question in plotly community that says that reversed axis ranges are still not supported in 3D.

http://community.plot.ly/t/reverse-z-axis-values/1817

So I think I should do it by myself...